# Change entry with number suffix to full number in r?

Tags: r

Can you change "1.00K" to "1,000" or "1.00M" to "1,000,000" in r? Currently listed as a character string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157381/thousand-separator-to-numeric-columns-in-r/71172863#71172863???

Comment: @Onyambu It looks like that is the reverse of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Do you need your results to be numeric or character?

Comment: Also how do you end up with `M` and `K`?? are you in any way formating from numeric to character that has M and K and then you want to revert back?

Comment: @Onyambu numeric please. We need it for comparisons. Ex.: makes it easier to compare "1.00M" to "1.00K".

Comment: @Onyambu The M and the K were provided in the dataset.

Comment: Welcome to SO. While your question seems clear in what you are asking, it is generally good practice to provide a reproducible example (reprex). Also, without constructing a wall of text, it is helpful to disclose what approaches you tried.

Answer (score 4):

If you need the result as numeric, you could do it with regular expressions:

```r
numbers <- c("5.00K", "1.00M", "100", "3.453M")

as.numeric(sub("^(\\d+\\.?\\d*).*$", "\\1", numbers)) *
  ifelse(grepl("K", numbers), 1000, 1) * 
  ifelse(grepl("M", numbers), 1e6, 1)
#> [1]    5000 1000000     100 3453000
```

Answer (score 4):

We may also do this by replacing the 'K', 'M' with `e3` and `e4` respectively using `str_replace` and then directly convert to `numeric`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_replace_all(str1, setNames(c("e3", "e6"), c("K", "M"))))
[1]    5000 1000000     100 3453000
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("5.00K", "1.00M", "100", "3.453M")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:

```
x <- "1.00K"
format(as.numeric(sub("K", "e3", x, fixed = TRUE)), big.mark = ",")
[1] "1,000"

options(scipen = 100)
y <- "1.00M"
format(as.numeric(sub("M", "e6", y, fixed = TRUE)), big.mark=",")
[1] "1,000,000"
```

- Explanation:

`sub("K", "e3", x, fixed = TRUE)`
gives
`"1.00e3"` (e.g.: `K` is replaced by `e3`)

and adding `as.numeric(..)`:

`as.numeric("1.00e3")`
gives
`1000`

and

wraping it around format(..., bigmark=","):

`format(as.numeric(sub("K", "e3", x, fixed = TRUE)), big.mark = ",")`
gives
`1,000`

- Now same procedure for `M` but here we need `e6`

Comment: I can see that the `e3` and `e6` values are controlling where the decimal point lands. However, while I can manipulate it (which is very useful) I'm afraid that don't understand it. Is this a value for the `replacement` argument of `sub`? I'm obviously not searching the documentation correctly.

Comment: Please see my update with the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The [`stringr`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_replace) library should address this. Try the following:

```r
# load library
library(stringr)

# construct a vector requiring the change
foo <-  c("1.00K", "bar")
foo

# replace values
foo <- str_replace_all(foo, pattern = "1.00K", replacement = "1,000")
foo
```

To make the other changes, like converting "1.00M" to "1,000,000", simply alter the value for the `replacement =` argument. When cleaning data, I often assemble all of these cleaning steps in a separate R script that gets called early in my R Markdown document.

Comment: This wouldn't work in the general case of a column of arbitrary numbers like `c("1.00K", "2.01K", "3.78M")` etc

Comment: I suppose you are correct as one would need a `str_replace_all` call for each unique number. Perhaps with regex's if the number ends with K remove the decimal and tack on three 0's, etc? Maybe that would be a more generally applicable approach for a long column of numbers like this.

Comment: I see your answer does just this. Taking note...thanks.